# Open Source ETL to load ActiveMQ data into a column-oriented database

Tags: database, data-visualization, data, data-extraction, integrations

Can anybody suggest me an open source tool which can integrate with activemq as a source and load data into any [columnar database management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) like greenplum/cassandra etc.

I have analysed Talend and Pentaho but their open source version do not have AMQ connectors.